# python integer division error - modulo by zero - BUT divisor != 0

Tags: python, division, modulo

I am new to doing simple math using python, so sorry if this is a silly question.

I have 8 variables that are all set to integers and these integers are used when performing a simple calculation.

```
a = 0
b = 17
c = 152
d = 1
e = 133
f = 19
g = 20
h = 0

answer = ( ( ( a / f ) + b + c ) - ( g + ( h / f ) ) ) / ( d / f )

print answer
```

When I run this code, I get the error, ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero.

I have read about this error and all documentation points towards my divisor being zero, but if I print this with the numbers as strings in place of the variables, I get:

```
( ( ( 0 / 19 ) + 17 + 152 ) - ( 20 + ( 0 / 19 ) ) ) / ( 1 / 19 )
```

Nowhere in this statement is the divisor zero.

Please let me know how I need to change my expression in order to get the answer 2831.  Note that I can change the type of the variables to a float or other.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably you are using `Python 2.x`, where `x / y` is an `integer division`.

So, in the below code: -

```
( 20 + ( 0 / 19 ) ) ) / ( 1 / 19 )
```

`1 / 19` is an `integer division`, which results in `0`. So the expression is essentially same as: -

```
( 20 + ( 0 / 19 ) ) ) / 0
```

Now you see where the error comes from.

---

You can add following import in you `python` code, to enforce floating-point division: -

```
from __future__ import division
```

Or you could cast one of the integers to a float, using either `float()` or just by adding `.0` to the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import division
```

and than do your calculation

it will cause the division to return floats

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Here's my code:

```
a = 0
b = 17
c = 152
d = 1
e = 133
f = 19
g = 20
h = 0

answer = ( ( ( a / f ) + b + c ) - ( g + ( h / f ) ) ) / ( d / f )

print(answer)
```

Nearly exactly same.